# Reabertura de Tópico - Manual Oficial de JavaScript

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

[Esse tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37356/existe-documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-oficial) recém criado era sobre uma pergunta simples a qual foi perguntada diretamente, sem floreios desnecessários como, na minha opinião, tantos outros tópicos que dão abertura para um assunto complexo e de respostas extensas e bem elaboradas com apenas algumas poucas linhas no tópico.

É bem verdade que uma busca rápida no Google poderia trazer a resposta, mas e se a intenção fosse mesmo apenas aumentar a base de conhecimento proposta pela Comunidade?

O brasofilo até tentou ajudar com um link para as informações da tag JavaScript mas, apesar de bem abrangente, não responde a dúvida do OP já que tecnicamente não existe um manual oficial de JavaScript. O MDN chega perto, abrange muito coisa, mas não é oficial.

Isso sem contar o fato que um iniciante em programação que tenha essa mesma dúvida, dificilmente chegaria a um veredicto através do texto apresentado na página de informações da tag.

Dito isso... Gostaria de fazer mais uma moção para reverter a exclusão desse tópico. Talvez este mereça uma editada para talvez agradar gregos e troianos, mas isso é algo para depois.

Comment: Bom, já tinha 2 votos para reabertura, dei o 3º e fiz uma edição para tentar validar a questão.

Comment: Eu gostaria de ouvir mais opiniões sobre isso. A pergunta é certamente objetiva, mas a resposta faria muito sentido como parte do wiki da tag.

Comment: O Sergio estava respondendo, eu estava respondendo e provavelmente essas respostas iriam salvar a pergunta do fechamento. Aí subitamente o AP removeu o pergunta.

Comment: Se esta foi reaberta, porque não reabrir [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37034/c-material-para-estudo#comment71231_37034) também? Ou manter ambas fechadas? Ambas acabam por ser sobre criar uma lista de recursos.

Comment: @Omni, não vejo como "manual oficial" pode gerar uma lista de links.